# Open JSON-File InternalStorage from different Activity (Android)

Tags: android, file, android-activity

My point it's the next. I just download a json file from the server when login it's done. I save it with the next code in activity login.class :

```
JSONObject json2 = jsonParser2.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
//3
try {
  FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("news.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  fos.write(json2.toString().getBytes());
  fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I just check in `/data/data/myapp/files/news.json` and the file is created with the right data.

My problem is in the next activity (A different activity). In this one I want to read the file and put it in a listview, but android emulator/device crashed when it's trying to access the file. (This is my code):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_noticias);
    try {
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}


public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("news.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

Please, can someone help me with this issue ?? How can i fixed or someone knows another method to read the file ??

Thanks for u time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the file from the `file system` (from wherever `internal` or `external` storage media) you used to save it.

Assets are used with those files that you embed in the app i.e put it in the `res/raw` or similar folder and then build the app.

Don't do this

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("news.json");
```

if you have stored the file on the app's sandboxed memory space. Use appropriate `File` class routines.

Comment: IT JUST WORK ONLY CHANGING THAT LINE FOR ->FileInputStream is = openFileInput("noticias.json");

THANKS ^^

Comment: you are welcome. you mean news.json or noticias.json?